# javascript image swapper is showing a box instead of my images

Tags: javascript

I'm getting a issue where none of my images can be seen, just a box. i've got 4 images that i want to swap every 2 seconds

```
<picture>
    <img src="" alt="" class="main-hobby">
    <div>
        <img class="image1" src="./Assets/slider-1.png" alt="person-learning-new-technology">
        <img class="image2" src="./Assets/slider-2.png" alt="a-house">
        <img class="image3" src="./Assets/slider-3.png" alt="person-playing-golf">
        <img class="image4" src="./Assets/slider-4.png" alt="xbox-controller">
    </div>
</picture>
```

Here's my javascript, i'm new to this so im not sure what is going on.

```
const image1 = document.querySelector('.image1')
const image2 = document.querySelector('.image2')
const image3 = document.querySelector('.image3')
const image4 = document.querySelector('.image4')
const images = [image1, image2, image3, image4];
let index = 0;

const mainHobby = document.querySelector('.main-hobby');

console.log(images);

function change() {
    mainHobby.src = images[index]
    index > 2 ? index = 0 : index ++;
    ;
}

window.onload = function () {
    setInterval (change, 2000);
}
```

and css if needed

```
.main-hobby {
     display: block;
     width: 70px;
     height: 70px;
     margin-bottom: 20%;
   }
```

thanks for any help you can give

[image: this is what i see]

Comment: `mainHobby.src = images[index].src`

Answer (score 1):

You have to set only the src attribute and not the entire img tag inside to maon-hobby container. Like that:

```js
const image1 = document.querySelector('.image1')
const image2 = document.querySelector('.image2')
const image3 = document.querySelector('.image3')
const image4 = document.querySelector('.image4')

const images = [image1, image2, image3, image4];
let index = 0;

const mainHobby = document.querySelector('.main-hobby');

// console.log(images);

function change() {
  console.log(index)
  let src = images[index].getAttribute('src');
  mainHobby.src = src
  console.log(mainHobby)
  index > 2 ? index = 0 : index ++;  
}

window.onload = function () {
   setInterval (change, 2000);
}
```

```css
.main-hobby {
  display: block;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  margin-bottom: 20%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200/green" alt="" class="main-hobby">

  <div>
    <img class="image1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200/green" alt="person-learning-new-technology">
    <img class="image2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200/gray" alt="a-house">
    <img class="image3" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200/red" alt="person-playing-golf">
    <img class="image4" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200/yellow" alt="xbox-controller">
  </div>
```

Comment: It's still not showing the images must be something other than the javascript?

Comment: This snippet works if you run it. Probably the images are wrongly referenced in your code. Open the browser console in the network tab, and see if there are any 404 comming up

Comment: @DanielCruz is a good point! It looks like something in SteveLopes code is already broken.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to set the `src` to an image element, you should be setting it to the image's `src`:

```
function change() {
    mainHobby.src = images[index].src;
    if (index >= images.length-1) {
        index = 0;
    } else {
        index++;
    }
}
```

Comment: That didnt solve it, but i can see how that should have worked